# Read more div with images expand/collapse Toggle excerpt/content

Tags: jquery, truncate

Okay, I've been spending all day trying to figure out the right approach for this, but have come out short, so maybe someone here can point me in the right direction.

Problem:
I have a div with class "article-content". There will be around 2-10 of these on the page. Each of them will contain output from a wysiwyg. i.e. texts wrapped in p-tags, some strong tags, em tags and even img tags.

I need to create a preview/excerpt version of these that wont show the images and will append a [...] to the end of x characters + a "read more" link. When this is clicked the full article will be shown including images.

Ive seen the following appraches:

1. Strip the content of the div after x characters and add [...] + link. This makes the content a bit fragile since it can strip end tags, and even strip the middle of an image tag resulting in broken html being outputtet.
2. Change the height on content element, and overflow:hidden;. This could result in an image overflowing out of the box - with parts of it inside, and even cut a line in half depending on the line-height vs. the content height. this makes the js very css dependant.
3. Create new content element with the first x characters and toggle display none/block on the short version and long version. This creates 2 instances of the text in the markup, which i would prefer. This would also make it impossible to take advantage of css transitions for the height when the elements expands.

I find it a little strange that i havent been able to find a bullet proof plugin for this supposedly simple - and much used - task. But maybe im just missing something. Maybe im google for the wrong terms. what is this thing offically called ? toggle expand? read-more-read-less? show more?

What would be considered the best approach? and is there a way to get around all these problems?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you want to implement it by yourself or using with jquery plugin?

Comment: both is fine.. if theres a good plugin, then i'd be more then happy with that. But the ones i've found have had problems as i see it..

Comment: Id be okay with writing it myself, but i feel like im missing something. What would be the best approach?

Comment: You can try this plugin
[click for link](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/)

Comment: thanks Dvir. I would use that if it were able to insert (...) where it breaks the text. but that plugin just hides the text in overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach i think, if you want it all client-side is to wrap your text with wrapper div.

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="text short">
      Long Text
  </div>
  <span class="read-more">read more</span>
```

the `.text.short` will be set to fixed height for example `height:100px;`
    the `read-more` will be set with click event that remove the short class, and add full class.

the Js will look like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".read-more").click(function(){

            var $elem = $(this).parent().find(".text");
            if($elem.hasClass("short"))
            {
                $elem.removeClass("short").addClass("full");

            }
            else
            {
                $elem.removeClass("full").addClass("short");

            }

        });
    });
```

the css like this:

```
.article {
   border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
   padding: 3px;
   margin: 2px;
}
.article .text {
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 17px;
   font-family: arial;
}
.article .text.short {
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.article .text.full {

}
.read-more {
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;    
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 3px;
   background-color: #06c;
   color: white;
   margin: 2px;
}
```

with the javascript code you can replace the characters, images to whatever you want.

I created for you full working example and look nice on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Ewe/)

**Edit**
add ellipsis with jquery.

see on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Ewe/1/)

Comment: Hi Dvir. Thank you so much for your work. It does seem to be the only approach that works. Its what i describe as the 2nd approach in my question. How would you go about adding the (...) to the last line in the short version. ?

Comment: See my edit at the bottom of the answer. now you have ellipsis and you can set what size of text you want.
If this answer helped you i'll be happy if you'll mark this answer and vote up for me.

Comment: Hi Dvir . that seems to fix the problem. Man you're good. I even tried to break it by adding tags right at the cutoff point (like <em> and <img>), but it doesnt break. how did you go about making sure that its not leaving open tags? if for ex i open an <em> 2 words before the cutoff point, and closes it </em> 6 words later. It cuts off where it needs to and auto-closes the em tag. I cant figure out how you did this from the code. Would you be able to explain that? but thank you - ill accept your answer here. best solution i've seen.

Comment: Im sorry Dvir , but after some testing i noticed that it does in fact break, if you use rich-text around the cutoff point. its fine for simple ones like <em> and <b> since html5 seems to auto-end them, but if you stick an <img> with a long src on  there the (...) disappears.

Comment: I'll try to find a soultion.
What do you want that will happen?
Replace the image with some text? like [...]?

Comment: its important that the cut off point doesn't break markup. And that te [...] will be inserted to the end of whatever text is left. Im starting to think this can't be done. But basically if the cut of is where the star is in this: `lorem <strong>ipsum dolor* sit amet</strong>. More lorem ipsum` then it need to become : `lorem <strong>ipsum dolor</strong>...` in the markup.

Comment: in other words the code needs to be intelligent enough to know what tags are missings its end tag, and then add that before the [...] no matter what the tag is. And if the cut off point is in the middle of the tag, i.e. `lorem <stro*ng>ipsum</strong>` then the code must cut before the tag instead. i.e. `lorem*<strong>impsum</strong>`

Comment: Ok I'll find a solution.