# How to achieve read More functionality with single div only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div>This is my content containing some general large text to display ...
   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,          when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type  specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into  electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in  the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

How can I achieve read more functionality of expanding content on clicking (...)
without any other nested Divs or

Tags "Just Single Div"

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks jonathon for edits.. save my life :)

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to make only the `...` clickable without nesting any other elements. You could make the whole `div` clickable, though. Would that work for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read more div with images expand/collapse Toggle excerpt/content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164436/read-more-div-with-images-expand-collapse-toggle-excerpt-content)

Comment: Not a duplicate . I mentioned I have a requirement to make it happen without nesting tags

Comment: @icke I want First line to be visible and if user want to read more then he should click (read more) or ... , Like scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like that:

HTML

```
<div class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

CSS

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".truncate").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("truncate");
});
```

Comment: Thanks A lot .. this is exactly  what i was looking for and also a small change for advancement ..Instead of "removeClass" "toggleClass" gives a shrink back functionality too

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var length = $("#content").text().length;
  var originalText = $("#content").text();
  var splittedText = "";
  
  if (length > 100) {
    splittedText = $("#content").text().substring(0, 100);
    splittedText += "...";
    $("#content").after("<input id='button_more' type='button' value='read more'/>");
  }
  
  $("#content").text(splittedText);
  
  $("#button_more").click(function() {    
    $("#content").text(originalText);
    $("#content").hide(0);
    $("#content").show(1000);
    $("#button_more").hide(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>read more test</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" style='text-align : justify'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur varius justo ac ante hendrerit, id convallis     felis fermentum. Fusce vehicula, eros ut blandit lobortis, dui nunc euismod massa, non placerat sapien dolor in libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent nec est in sapien finibus bibendum. Proin turpis odio, pulvinar id convallis ac, condimentum ac enim. Vestibulum eu ante sit amet nisl commodo hendrerit vitae non tortor. Fusce feugiat magna at tempus dictum. Sed pharetra volutpat risus sit amet rhoncus. Morbi maximus lectus purus, venenatis sodales orci luctus eget. Ut viverra commodo tempus. Morbi varius diam id ex dignissim pulvinar. Aliquam ac tincidunt lectus. Nulla pulvinar dolor eros, at porttitor lacus sagittis ut.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This snippet cut a text by saving the first 100 caracters, adding "...", and a button which let the user show the whole text by clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your text has multiple paragraphs, you can split it:

```
var size = $("#" + read_more_id + " p").size();
```

and implement something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/451zncwn/1/. This example also automatically adds "read more" and "read less" links.