# in jQuery toggle active and deactive divs in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

In wordpress category page,i want toggle active and deactivate class in post.

When i click on Read more button remove class deactivate and add class active

using code :

Its in loop

```
 <div class="post-content deactivate" id="postfull_con<?php echo $postid; ?>" >
                <?php the_content();?>
            </div>

<div class="post_less" id="post-<?php echo $postid; ?>">
                <p>Read more </p>
            </div>
```

loop end

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#post-<?php echo $postid; ?>').on('click', function() {
     if(jQuery('#postfull_con<?php echo $postid; ?>').hasClass('active')){
           jQuery('#postfull_con<?php echo $postid; ?>').removeClass('active');
           jQuery('#postfull_con<?php echo $postid; ?>').addClass('deactivate');
        }else{
           jQuery('#postfull_con<?php echo $postid; ?>').addClass('active');
           jQuery('#postfull_con<?php echo $postid; ?>').removeClass('deactivate');
        }
        });
});
```

Problem is its not deactivate when i click on other post (read more)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164436/read-more-div-with-images-expand-collapse-toggle-excerpt-content

Comment: Why did you put `php` code in your `jquery`? Just target the classes.

Comment: in this example, there have same problem, take look on example [http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Ewe/] when i click on read more , its open fully . but when i click on next "read more". i want previews one read less

Comment: @dingo_d its ok .. please answer what i have problem

Comment: @dingo_d if you have solution with classes please let me know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.post-content {}` should have the CSS rules of the deactivate class

HTML:

```
<div class="post-content" id="postfull_con<?php echo $postid; ?>" >
    <?php the_content();?>
</div>

<div class="post_less" data-id="<?php echo $postid; ?>">
    <p>Read more </p>
</div>
```

Js:

You don't need a bind on each post id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.post-less').on('click', function() {
        var postId = $(this).data('id');

        //Close all other open posts
        //It's a bad practice to remove one class to add another for a specific funtionality to happen
        //The default state of post-content should be the "deactivate" class and when you add active rules should be overwriten.
        $('.post-content').removeClass('active');

        //Look for the full post and activated
        $('#postfull_con' + postId).addClass('active');
    });
});
```